# loadCSV conditional handling with regex (Syntaxproblem)

Tags: regex, csv, cypher

A csv file contains in one column either a date format like "2016-12-01T00:00:00+01" or a different value like an integer.

My idea was while running the loadCSV to make a switch like an if-else statement to have either turned the date into an unix timestamp or do not change the value at all. To detect if its a date or not I tried to use a regex.

I came up with the following statement

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///xxx.csv" AS row 
FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
FOREACH(n IN (CASE row.dataValue=~ "/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})[+-](\d{2})\"  THEN [] else [row.dataValue= apoc.date.parse(row.dataValue, "s", "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+01")] END) |
CREATE (d:datapoint {data: row.dataValue})
return d
```

THis throws an error:
Invalid input 'd': expected ...  which seems to refer to the first letter d in the regex.

a) What would be a correct syntax

b) Is the statement at all correct to get what I want?

Any hint is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [0-9] instead of \d. I don't know if that is your issue but your regex seems fine (except that first forward slash at the very beginning).

Try something like this:

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T(?:[0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}[-+][0-9]{2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/fqydFq/1

Comment: Thanks, indeed that fixed the issue. Also the link was very helpful, didnt knew that tool! Awesome.